# Google play services is missing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have included the google play services lib in my project but when i run it i get an error: [google-play-services](/questions/tagged/google-play-services) is missing. I am using code of google maps in my project and i can compile it with now problem. My only guess is that in my last git commits i had an ignore file and maybe this caused the problem. How can i fix the problem? The logcat is the following:

```
02-28 21:16:26.700: E/AndroidRuntime(30360): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 21:16:26.700: E/AndroidRuntime(30360):    at .MapActivity.setMapSettings (MapActivity.java:226)
02-28 21:16:26.700: E/AndroidRuntime(30360):    at .MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:88)
02-28 21:16:26.700: E/AndroidRuntime(30360):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
02-28 21:16:26.700: E/AndroidRuntime(30360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

and the line 226 is the following:

> uiSettings = map.getUiSettings();

Comment: as i read in the [android developers](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) is it possible this problem to be caused because i haven't installed the last google play services in the sdk manager?

Comment: please add the code.  Also, before start using library related classes, you should check if it's installed on the phone. http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

i have just solved it. the google services have been updated in my device and the google play service lib of my project was in an old version .I updated it and the problem has been sovled!

Comment: Are u sure only adding `google-play-services.jar` would solve the problem?